# command to display Excel after saving

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

This is the vba Command that I am using to make a spreadsheet and save it:

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "query_alldata1", "C:\All_Data_2014.xlsx", True

I also want it to open or display automatically on the screen. I would appreciate any guide.

This is how my subroutin looks like:

```
Private Sub btnAlldatagen_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_btnAlldatagen_Click
Dim stDocName As String

stDocName = "query_alldata1"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "query_alldata1", "C:\All_Data_2014.xlsx", True


'Workbooks.Open "C:\All_Data_2014.xls"
MsgBox ("Preparing all Data Report")
Exit_btnAlldatagen_Click:
Exit Sub
Err_btnAlldatagen_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_btnAlldatagen_Click

End Sub
```

I am using Workbooks.open command but it does not open the worksheet.

Comment: tnx but this does not help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, this one is easy.

After

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "query_alldata1", "C:\All_Data_2014.xlsx", True
```

Place:

```
Dim xl As Object
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With xl
  .Visible = True
  .Workbooks.Open ("C:\All_Data_2014.xlsx")
  '.Do other things with excel here

  '.Workbooks("Test1.xlsm").Close , False '<-- Uncomment to close workbook
  '.Quit '<-- Uncomment to close Excel
End With

'Set xl = Nothing <-- Uncomment to set Excel to Nothing
```

Comment: Also worth trying is `Set xl = GetObject("C:\All_Data_2014.xlsx")`. This will use an existing excel instance if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reference to the Excel runtime library (Microsoft Excel * Object Library), and work with Excel VBA.

```
Dim xlApp as Excel.Application
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\All_Data_2014.xlsx")
xlApp.Visible

Set xlApp = Nothing
```

IF you are planning on doing this multiple times, you should make sure to create the `xlApp` variable once at the beginning of your code, since opening Excel is slow.